# Retrieve data from mysql database and insert it in a table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I design 3 pages in html with bootstrap framework, one is i can insert data to database the second it shows subject and date of the data i inserted in database in a html table and i want the 3rd page to get data from database when i click on recorded data in table and show it in the 3rd page.

```
|-------|----------|--------------|
| No    |   Subject   | Date      |
|-------|----------|--------------|
|  1    |      A   |   2016       |
|-------|----------|--------------|
|  2    |      B   |   2016       |
|-------|----------|--------------|
```

when i click on A i want to get data about A project from Database and when i click on B i want to get details about B project in another Page from databse.

i don't have any idea how to do that with php and html.

sorry for bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Project No with GET Variable and retrieve that data with that ID in 3rd page like this :

Second Page :

```
<tr>
    <td><?=$project->no;?></td>
    <td><?=$project->subject;?></td>
    <td><a href="localhost/3rdpage.php?id=<?=$project->no;?>">Details</a></td>
</tr>
```

Third Page :

```
$projectNo = $_GET['id'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM project WHERE no = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($projectNo));
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```